# how to interpret the RTL report after synthesis in Xilinx?

Tags: xilinx, synthesis, rtl, virtex-series-fpga

I did verilog code of a circuit. It was simulating well and giving output correct after Simulation. Now i did synthesis, the RTL schematic after synthesis showing some green and red box. Is it indicating any kind of error?
Please give any comment to clear this confusion.
Thank you.

[image]

Asking about the red and green boxes which i highlight using white color lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error.

Green Box: start of a wire.
Red Box: end of a wire.

I don't know why ISE's RTL viewer shows these boxes. Inputs and outputs are defined by the right and left side of sub-schematic...

Comment: I presume they are shown on the net you have selected really just to highlight connections - its far easier to spot a big box when zoomed out in a big schematic.